# WPF, points are different to RenderTargetBitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, crop

My problem is that the Int32Rect points are different from the ones in my canvas. I attempted to use dpi as suggested as a solution to other problems but I could not figure out how to use it.

```
private void bttnExportFB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)mainCanvas.ActualWidth,
        (int)mainCanvas.ActualHeight, 96d, 96d, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
        rtb.Render(mainCanvas);

        CroppedBitmap crop = new CroppedBitmap(rtb, new Int32Rect((int)(173 ), (int)(360), (int)(353 ), (int)(540 )));

        BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(crop));

        using (var fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("logo.bmp"))
        {
            pngEncoder.Save(fs);
        }

    }
```

-update-
on canvas the rectangle which created by positions of the inteRect32, has different area at rtb.

Comment: Please explain whta you mean by "points are different". What do you expect and what do you observe instead?